# Curve is getting bigger when using array mod on a circle

Tags: modifiers

I was trying to make a tire for a car that I'm modelling but every time I add count on the array mod the tire gets bigger.

How do I fix this and what did I do wrong?

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzun6.png)

[image: This is what keeps on happening]

[image]

[image: Version 2.93.1? Could the version change what happens?]

[image]

Comment: Does the object have some unapplied *Scale*?

Comment: I don't think so but I tried control a which didn't help

Comment: I think you're gonna need to [edit] your post and add some more pictures of the modifier pane and any other details you think might help.

Comment: Or provide your blend file, then we can help you for sure…

Comment: I tried adding the blend file im not sure if its going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is a bit messy, try to put the origins of each object at their geometry, apply the rotations, put the curve and the object at the same position, etc.

A quick fix is to flatten your curve called *BezierCurve* on the Z axis, you can do it in *Object* mode and in that case apply the rotation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I got it fixed ( although I took the short cut)!